# Is there Scribd Api component available for Cakephp 1.2

Tags: cakephp, components, cakephp-1.2, scribd

Is there scribd cakephp component for scribd API.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Not that I know of, if you do create one, be sure to pop it in the Bakery for us all to enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it, but it would be a great way to learn cake + REST